# keras - keyword initial_state not understood

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a Seq-2-Seq model in keras but I am having trouble resolving an error from `SimpleRNN`:

`TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'initial_state')`

Here is a small example:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, SimpleRNN, Embedding

encoder_input = Input(shape=(16,))
encoder_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=40, output_dim=12)(encoder_input)
encoder_rnn_out, encoder_rnn_state = SimpleRNN(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=False, return_state=True)(encoder_embedding)

decoder_input = Input(shape=(11,)) 
decoder_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=12, output_dim=12)(decoder_input) 
decoder_rnn = SimpleRNN(32, activation='relu', initial_state=encoder_rnn_state, return_sequences=True)(decoder_embedding) 
decoder_predictions = Dense(12, activation='softmax')(decoder_rnn)

model = Model(encoder_input, decoder_predictions)
```

These are my tensorflow and keras versions (I have already uninstalled and reinstalled them using `pip`)

```
$ conda list -n py36 | grep tensorflow
tensorflow                1.13.1                    <pip>
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0                    <pip>
$ conda list -n py36 | grep Keras
Keras                     2.2.4                     <pip>
Keras-Applications        1.0.7                     <pip>
Keras-Preprocessing       1.0.9                     <pip>
```

My `~/.keras/keras.json`

```
{
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float32",
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem, and found answer.

Change this

```py
decoder_rnn = SimpleRNN(32, activation='relu', initial_state=encoder_rnn_state, return_sequences=True)(decoder_embedding)
```

to this.

```py
decoder_rnn = SimpleRNN(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(decoder_embedding, initial_state=encoder_rnn_state)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SimpleRNN` constructor does not take `initial_state` as input argument. You probably meant to use the `kernel_initializer` or the `recurrent_initializer` argument instead.

See https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/.

Comment: in the documentation you linked, it says "You can specify the initial state of RNN layers symbolically by calling them with the keyword argument initial_state", so I assume this should be true for `SimpleRNN` as well. I don't mean to use `kernel_initializers` or `recurrent_initializers` as I would like to initialize the state and not the weight matrices.

Comment: That is True for the `RNN` class, not for the `SimpleRNN` :) maybe try use that.